# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\Common\Aws' not found in test.php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk

I installed AWS PHP SDK v3 based on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html using composer method. Tried a simple example but getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\Common\Aws' not found in test.php
```

Code:

```
<?php

// Include the SDK using the Composer autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Common\Aws;

$aws = Aws::factory('./cfg.php');

/* CODE BELOW WORKS FINE BY ITSELF
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-west-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => '***',
        'secret' => '***'
    ],
]);

$result = $s3->listBuckets();

foreach ($result['Buckets'] as $bucket) {
    // Each Bucket value will contain a Name and CreationDate
    echo "{$bucket['Name']} - {$bucket['CreationDate']}\n";
}
*/
?>
```

My PHP version:

```
PHP 7.1.0alpha2 (cli) (built: Jun 27 2016 22:39:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

I tried including aws.phar instead but still did not work.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong namespace. Why are you using `Aws\Common\Aws`? Looking at the [source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) I can't find that namespace.

Comment: @sebastianForsberg I followed some example from AWS site. My intention is to use KMS API from AWS. I need to run "$result = $client->listKeys([]);" - so need a client object - how do I get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `./cfg.php` contains, but if you follow your commented code.

You could use [Aws\Kms\KmsClient](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Kms.KmsClient.html) and do something like:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = Aws\Kms\KmsClient::factory(/*Config Array or Guzzle Http Client*/);

$result = $client->listKeys();
```

Just so you know, `Aws\Kms\KmsClient` is nearly the exact same client as `Aws\AwsClient`

[Further info on that config needed to create the client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/configuration.html#client-configuration-options)